# Control the order of ember promise resolution?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've been following the tutorial, using ember 2.9.1, node 6.9.1, chrome 53.0.2785.143 and OS/X 10.11.6.

When I create the component described here:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/tutorial/autocomplete-component/

I end up with a race condition. If I enter the character p into the input and very rapidly hit backspace, I end up with the models filtered by the character p but no input in the text field.

Some console logging suggests this is happening because the second promise (which returns all the models, since the input is empty) is resolving first, and the first promise (returning the filtered models) resolves second.

Is there anything that can be done about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For concurrency purposes, there is an addon called: [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs). You can use it for all your async operations.

Also [ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/) uses this addon. It is a powerful, auto-complete select component. I can suggest you to use it.

Edit 2016-10-25: here's the updated code using ember-concurrency which solves the race condition (now with correct property name):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['list-filter'],
  value: '',

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('filter')('').then((results) => this.set('results', results));
  },

  handleFilterEntryTask: task(function * () {
    const filterInputValue = this.get('value');
    const filterAction = this.get('filter');

    const filterResults = yield filterAction(filterInputValue);
    this.set('results', filterResults);

  }).keepLatest(),

  actions: {
    handleFilterEntry() {
      this.get('handleFilterEntryTask').perform();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this, but I'd like to post the resulting source code too! I'll put it in another answer, but feel free to copy it into yours.

Comment: Note that you can remove the redundancy of the `handleFilterEntry` action simply performing `handleFilterEntryTask` and just use the `perform handleFilterEntryTask` anywhere you would have wanted to use `action 'handleFilterEntry'`. Also, in more recent Embers (I think >= 2.4 ?) you can just use `action handleFilterEntryTask` and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Further to [ykaragol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4545506/ykaragol)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40232550/1423361), here's my updated code using [ember-concurrency](http://ember-concurrency.com/#/docs) which solves the race condition:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['list-filter'],
  value: '',

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('filter')('').then((results) => this.set('results', results));
  },

  handleFilterEntryTask: task(function * () {
    const filterInputValue = this.get('value');
    const filterAction = this.get('filter');

    const filterResults = yield filterAction(filterInputValue);
    this.set('results', filterResults);

  }).keepLatest(),

  actions: {
    handleFilterEntry() {
      this.get('handleFilterEntryTask').perform();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came up with one solution: store the promise against the component, and check it has not been superseded when resolving it, only changing state if it has not. Is there a better / more idiomatic way of doing this?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['list-filter'],
  value: '',
  currentPromise: null,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('filter')('').then((results) => this.set('results', results));
  },

  actions: {
    handleFilterEntry() {
      const filterInputValue = this.get('value');
      const filterAction = this.get('filter');

      const thePromise = filterAction(filterInputValue);
      this.set('currentPromise', thePromise);

      thePromise.then((filterResults) => {
        if (thePromise == this.get('currentPromise')) {
          this.set('results', filterResults);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```